# Check LAN connection by javascript

Tags: javascript, connection, lan

I have deployed a web application in a machine, which is connected to all the other client machine in the LAN. While client is using the web app through browser I need to check whether the LAN connection exist for each request by javascript.

I have googled a lot about this, but all the content are regarding the internet connection and not regarding the LAN connection. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these other machines run some kind of apps or api services in them ?

Comment: @BrijRajSingh No. It is just use to access the web app using browser.

Comment: I think you need to look at the Network information API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API

Answer (score 1):

Try this one : Works for me :)

```
function hostReachable() {

  // Handle IE and more capable browsers
  var xhr = new ( window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest )( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
  var status;

  // Open new request as a HEAD to the root hostname with a random param to bust the cache
  xhr.open( "HEAD", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/?rand=" + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000), false );

  // Issue request and handle response
  try {
    xhr.send();
    return ( xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status === 304 );
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

[**Reference**](https://gist.github.com/jpsilvashy/5725579)